# Simulate CSRF attack in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, csrf

I'm trying to get an understanding of how CSRF tokens work, currently my goal is to create a situation where the CSRF attack is possible. I'm hosting two Django apps locally on different ports. I access one by localhost:8000, the other by 127.0.0.1:5000 -- that ensures cookies are not shared between apps.
There's an API view

```
class ModifyDB(APIView):
    
    def post(self,request,format=None):
       
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({'db modified'})

        else:
            return Response({'you need to be authenticated'})
```

which shouldn't be accessed by unauthenticated users.

The "malicious" site has a button that's supposed to trigger the attack when a user is logged on the target site:

```
const Modify = () => {

    const onClick = async e => { e.preventDefault();
        
        const instance = axios.create({
            withCredentials: true,
            baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
         })
         
        const res = await  instance.post('/api/modifydb');
        return res.data
    }

  return (
    <button class = 'btn' onClick = {onClick}> send request </button>
  )
}
```

My authentication settings are as follows:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
     
        'my_proj.settings.CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication',
       
    ],
}
```

where `CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication` is a custom class that disables csrf protection for my educational purposes:

```
class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return
```

`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` is also disabled.
Both `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` are set to true. My question is: what am I doing wrong, because when I'm logged in on the attacked site this axios request from the malicious site returns    `"you need to be authenticated"` response.
I expected that somehow sessionid cookie would be included and request would be successful (which is the logic behind this type of attack if I'm understanding it correctly).

**UPDATE**

I tried to use a form

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/api/modifydb" method="POST">    
    <input type="submit" value="make a malicious request"/>
</form>
```

instead of the axios request. It works with this additional setting:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

while my previous code for request still doesn't work even with this new setting.
Now, I don't get what is the difference between POST requests from a form and from axios regarding cookies attachment. And does SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE if enabled prevents this type of attack completely?

Comment: Look at the browser console, Network > Cookies tab for the malicious request. Does this contain information why certain cookies were not sent?

Comment: Heiko Theißen, no, this tab is empty. And there's also no mention of any cookies in headers for the malicious request